# How to use same instance of service in pop up window?

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, popupwindow, angular12

I am trying to use a communication service to send some data between different angular components. But I am facing an issue when the child component is opened inside a pop-up window. Since it is a separate angular app itself. So it's taking a different instance of the service and thus I am unable to send data.

This is my communication Service.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class CommunicatingService {
  private subject = new Subject<any>();
  sub = this.subject.asObservable()
  constructor() {}

  nextSub(data: any) {
    this.subject.next(data)
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you provide the `CommunicatingService`?

Comment: in providers of app.module.ts

Comment: Can't you just show a dialog instead of opening an entire popup window for showing that component?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu All I have to do is to convert the angular JS code to angular12. So I am replicating all the things they have done in angularJS code. Previously they were taking reference of the parent window and then using $broadcasting to send data. But since now I don't want to use $broadcasting I have created this service. Is there a way to inject the same service in the popup window? Replacing the popup window is out of scope.

Comment: Are you opening it with `window.open`? If you do, then [you receive a WindowProxy object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#return_value) back. You should look into how to get the information you need from this and relay it back to your components using the `CommunicatingService`. As you mentioned, there's like another application altogether, so there is no way you can share this service instance between them.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Yes I am using window.open. So basically the data I want to send is an event that is being triggered later on. So I cannot send the data initially. But I will take a look at the resources you have provided. Thanks for the help.